# Is the Sullustan in the Last Jedi Nien Numb?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, the-last-jedi

Not far into the Last Jedi on the cruiser, we see a Sullustan pilot who looks like Lando's co-pilot from Return of the Jedi, Nien Numb. Later, we see this same Sullustan

> Inside the fortress as they prepare for annihilation.

Is this, in fact, Nien Numb, or merely another Sullustan pilot? And is it clear that he

> escapes on the Falcon?

Comment: I had the same question while watching the movie, which was answered in the credits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Yes

Confirmed by [SW Databank Entry](https://www.starwars.com/databank/nien-nunb):

> A native of Sullust, Nien Nunb was a smuggler who fought for both the Rebel Alliance and the Resistance during his long career. An expert pilot, he served as Lando Calrissian’s co-pilot aboard the Millennium Falcon during the Battle of Endor, flew an X-wing in the raid on Starkiller Base and **survived the First Order’s assault on Crait.** He was then killed fighting for freedom at Exegol.

Emphasis mine

[image: Here is an image of him in TLJ]

Nien Nunb was played by returner [Mike Quinn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Quinn_(puppeteer)) and is present as part of Poe's Squadron in TFA and TLJ.

The original performer, Mike Quinn, has [IMDB credit for TLJ as Nien Nunb](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0703934/)

[Nien Nunb will return](https://movieweb.com/star-wars-8-nien-nunb/) as an unconfirmed testimonial before filming

> He survives to the end of the film and is present on the Millenium Falcon.

Comment: It's nice that they got the original performer.

Comment: @Valorum I added the IMDB credit, and I put the spoiler tag around the end because it is technically a spoiler for the end, if there is a better way to do it or you don't consider it privileged info I'll remove it.

Comment: @WraithLeader - It's ok now. I'd still like proof positive that he survived.

Comment: @Valorum I added the SW Databank listing too. I would as well, we will likely need screen caps to do that though so it may take a bit. I have seen it twice though and I specifically remember trying to nail down who was alive and who was not at the end of the film but human memory is also faulty so :/ I'm still looking though

Comment: @Valorum there is proof positive since he appeared in whatever that last film is. I totally forgot to add back to this when it came out.

Comment: PS why tf did they have to kill him off, neither him nor Ackbar deserved to die so unceremoniously but I guess that's how war is

Comment: An improvement. I'd upvote it a second time if I could.

Comment: I'll see if I can grab some screens from the Falcon later